Change header icons in MediaWiki Vector 2022
I am trying to update the coloring of the icons in the header for the MediaWiki Vector 2022 template on my Wiki, but I can't seem to figure it out.
I have updated the color of the header to black, and want to make these icons white in the same way Wikipedia have changed them if you switch to dark mode.
I am undating the CSS in the MediaWiki:Vector.css page.
Any help is appreciated.
I have looked in the Vector skin to see where these are generated from, but can't seem to locate either the CSS or the icons.
